# Why do I get different urls for the same content?

Tags: facebook, google-chrome-devtools, mpeg-dash

I am debugging a session of streaming of `Facebook Live` and I have an url of `.m4v` type which source is https://video-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net. With other connection in other place I have this url: https://video.fagp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net.

why do I have different urls for the same content?

It could be depend of the connection or the place (the distance between the two places are around 2 kilometers)?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: What I do not understand is that if it comes from the same domain server it is because they are different source url

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: With the same content but in different places I have different sources of url, in this example I have https://video-mad1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/ and in other place with the same computer I have https://video.fagp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/.

Comment: Ok? So Facebook is giving you different URLs.

Comment: Sorry I am new in this, I thought that all the content of the server of FbVideo had the same _nc_ht parameter.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content distribution networks (CDNs) distribute servers all over, to help serve content as close to the user as possible.  This reduces latency, generally increases throughput, and cuts down on traffic load going over longer haul links that tend to be more restricted in the bandwidth they have available.

When you put content up to a CDN node, it's generally distributed to at least some other places.  Therefore, it's entirely possible to have different URLs to the same content.

You might also find this interesting:  https://anuragbhatia.com/2018/03/networking/isp-column/mapping-facebooks-fna-cdn-nodes-across-the-world/